# What's the difference between a JavaScript object and an OO/UML/Java object?

Tags: java, javascript, oop, uml

In standard OO, as defined by UML, and instantiated, e.g., by Java and C#, there is a certain concept of objects as instances of classes. What's the difference between this classical concept of objects and a JavaScript object?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JavaScript objects are different from classical OO/UML (C++/Java/C# etc.) objects. In particular, they ***need not instantiate a class***. And they can have their own (instance-level) methods in the form of method slots, so they do not only have (ordinary) ***property slots***, but also ***method slots***. In addition they may also have ***key-value slots***. So, they may have three different kinds of slots, while classical objects (called "instance specifications" in UML) only have property slots.

JavaScript objects can be used in many different ways for different purposes. Here are five different use cases for, or possible meanings of, JavaScript objects:

1. A ***record*** is a set of property slots like, for instance,

```js
    var myRecord = { firstName:"Tom", lastName:"Smith", age:26}
```

2. An ***associative array*** (or 'hash map') is a set of key-value slots. It supports look-ups of *values* based on *keys* like, for instance,

```js
    var numeral2number = { "one":"1", "two":"2", "three":"3"}
```

which associates the value "1" with the key "one", "2" with "two", etc. A key need not be a valid JavaScript identifier, but can be any kind of string (e.g. it may contain blank spaces).

3. An ***untyped object*** does not instantiate a class. It may have property slots and method slots like, for instance,

```js
    var person1 = {  
      lastName: "Smith",  
      firstName: "Tom",
      getInitials: function () {
        return this.firstName.charAt(0) + this.lastName.charAt(0); 
      }  
    };
```

4. A ***namespace*** may be defined in the form of an untyped object referenced by a global object variable, the name of which represents a namespace prefix. For instance, the following object variable provides the main namespace of an application based on the Model-View-Controller (MVC) architecture paradigm where we have three subnamespaces corresponding to the three parts of an MVC application:

```js
    var myApp = { model:{}, view:{}, ctrl:{} };
```

5. A ***typed object*** `o` that instantiates a class defined by a JavaScript constructor function `C` is created with the expression

```js
    var o = new C(...)
```

The type/class of such a typed object can be retrieved with the introspective expression

```js
    o.constructor.name  // returns "C"
```

See my [JavaScript Summary](http://web-engineering.info/SummariesCheatsheetsPosters) for more on JavaScript objects.

Comment: Interesting. However I would suggest to remove UML from the comparison, as it appears that UML does not imply a strongly type language, even if it was designed with class based language in mind, and prototype based languages are not incompatible with UML.  Consider in this regard the definition of a classifier:  "A Classifier represents a classification of instances according to their Features".  I don't think this implies that the class of an object is fixed.  See also this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/69637013/3723423 - By the way, is your link still valid?

Comment: But the main issue here is not dynamic classification (which is neither supported in Java nor in JS), but the possibilities of objects (a) not instantiating any class, and (b) having method slots. [Doesn't the JavaScript Sumary link work for you?]

Comment: If an object shares no feature with any class, it's still an object. Then the prototyping creates implicitly some kind of classes, all this seems not incompatible with UML. - The link shows an almost empty page with a link to a document with a Russian title. So I wanted to be sure the page wasn't cyber-squatted in the meantime.

Comment: UML does not allow creating objects that do not instantiate a class (they say "A CreateObjectAction is an Action that creates a direct instance of a given Classifier"), while JS does allow this. No, the linked page is okay, it contains three links: (1) to an English HTML document, (2) to a Russian HTML document, and (3) to a PDF.

Comment: Interesting article with a lot of valuable information.   I understand that instantiating  an object that doesn't belong to any class in JS is anyhow creating an instance of `Object`, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object : "Nearly all objects in JavaScript are instances of Object", which seems to make it compatible with the CreateObjectAction.

Comment: It may be "compatible" with UML in the very weak sense that even JS objects that have not been created by instantiating a class are implicitly instances of the (abstract) top-level class `Object`. But then I would still maintain that such an object is "untyped" in the sense that it does  not have any specific class as its type, while any Java object does have such a specific class as its type.

Answer (score 3):

Along with the above you can add the below mentioned point:

1. Javascript Objects are mutable(we can add properties) where as Java Objects are immutable(we cannot add properties but we can change the value of the property by means of setters). When i say mutable one can add some additional property to the Javascript object. Say for example.

   `var person = 
   {
   firstName: "John",
   secondName: "Deer",
   }`

later on we can change it by adding additional properties. Say

```
Person.age = 25;
```

after this step Person will change to

`{firstName: "John", secondName: "Deer", age: 25}`

Where as this way of adding properties to the instantiated object is not possible in the case of Java.

2. Javascript Objects can be instantiated in many ways

**Using Literals**

```
var person = {firstName:"Deen",lastName:"Deer"}
```

**Using Javascripts new Object**

```
var person = new Object();
person.firstName = "John";
erson.lastName = "Deer";
```

**Using Function**

```
function Person(firstName, lastName){
this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

and you can create person object as

```
var person = new Person("John","Deer");
```