# Can behavior of subclasses vary according to traditional modeling?

Tags: inheritance, uml, subclass, class-diagram, superclass

I developed a class diagram, where I'm not sure if I understood the role of superclasses.

In my diagram, user is a superclass, but I still have different roles of users that have different behavior. Is it allowed to override behavior of subclasses or is that fundamentally wrong?

Is there a better design for this case?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a subclass can redefine/override the behavior of a superclass.  So `Blocked user`, `Normal user` and `Moderator user` could each override some behavior of `User` and add their own behavior on top.

[UML allows the class of an object to change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69637013/3723423) during its lifecycle.  But most programming languages don't.  This means that even if your design is fine in theory,  in practice you will not be able to implement it:  when you create a `Normal user`,  you'd not be able to transform it into a `Blocked user`.

You should therefore **[prefer composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)**:  you'd have an association between `User` and `User role` and let `User role` be specialized into `Blocked user`, `Normal user` and `Moderator user`.  So you keep the user, but change the role to change behavior.  In fact, you could go one step further and use the [**State design pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

[image]

***Unrelated hint**:  when you consider to redefine behavior of a subclass,  it's sound practice to design according to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) as much as possible.*